# Download a webpage to a text file

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I have the following code which works.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim webClient1 As New WebClient()
        webClient1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
        webClient1.DownloadFile("http://www.bmreports.com/servlet/com.logica.neta.bwp_MarketIndexServlet?displayCsv=true", "C:\temp\stream.txt")
    End Sub

End Module
```

This creates the text file but it does download all the html as well.  How can I omit this and just get the text that is displayed on the page?

Comment: Then you need to parse whole html text, extract required text (using regex/manaually) and insert into text-file.

Comment: Use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse the html. There's no "plain-text-mode" in a html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the html tags from the document using Regex:

```
  Dim source as string = File.ReadAllText("C:\temp\stream.txt")

  'Clean html tags
  source = StripTagsRegex(source)

  'Strip function

  Private Function StripTagsRegex(source As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", String.Empty)
  End Function
```

Here you have an example of thir regex, it extracts only text:

http://regexr.com?36ori

Comment: Carlos, can you add multiple replaces to regex as I want to replace the \ with a carriage return.

Comment: You can just do : Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", String.Empty).Replace("\","\n")